# Google spreadsheets or Excel, cell matches item from seprate sheet's column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Sheet 1:

```
Value, Populate me
Value 1, blank_1
Value 2, blank_2
```

Sheet 2:

```
Populate X, Populate Y
Value 1, Y1
X2, Value 2
X3, Y3
```

How do I tell 'Sheet 1'!blank_1 to automatically equal "Populate X" from Sheet2 since it matches one of the values in "Populate X"'s column. Similarly, 'Sheet 1'!blank_2 should automatically equal "Populate Y".

**Update:**

I have created a public Google Spreadsheet to better illustrate the problem:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhvDIvanE182dDFwU1VseHhaT2JIT0FoYXNQOVFwUWc&usp=sharing

Comment: In Google Sheets, the comma delimiter in functions will not work in locales that use a comma for a decimal separator. However, the semi-colon delimiter will work in *all* locales. It is really the discretion of the user, but it is generally recommended to use the semi-colon delimiter in Sheets due to it being universally supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google spreadsheets you can try something like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(match(A2;Data!$A$2:$A$5;0)>0;Data!$A$1;"");IFERROR(IF(match(A2;Data!$B$2:$B$5;0)>0;Data!$B$1;0);""))
```

Comment: Tried this and I could not get it to work. I even tried it on the same spreadsheet. Do you have a public Google Spreadsheet that shows this?

Comment: I added a public Google Spreadsheet to the question if you could kindly show how this works.

Comment: You can simplify slightly, and also automatically populate down the column, using `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2:A;Data!A2:A;0);Data!A1);IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2:A;Data!B2:B;0);Data!B1))))`

Answer (score 0):

This works but looks to have potential for simplification!:

> =IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2;Data!A:A;1;0)=A2;Data!$A$1);IF(VLOOKUP(A2;Data!B:B;1;0)=A2;Data!$B$1));"")

*Edited* to reflect @AdamL's comment under OP.